# jQuery show/hide based on select dropdown not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to show/hide `<div>`'s based on values chosen from a `select` drop-down menu.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selReport">
  <option value="Report One">Report One</option>
  <option value="Report Two">Report Two</option>
  <option value="Report Three">Report Three</option>
  <option value="Report Four">Report Four</option>
</select

<div id="Report One" class="description">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div id="Report Two" class="description">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I'm using the following jQuery snippet to hide the `<div>`'s and then show them based on what is selected in the drop-down menu:

**jQuery**

```
$('.description').hide();
$('#selReport').change(function () {
  $('description').hide()
  $("[id='" + this.value + "'").show();
});
```

When a new option is selected from the drop-down menu the previous `<div>` that was displayed doesn't hide. It stays displayed and I don't know why. Can someone offer a suggestion?

Comment: Remove the spaces and it should work fine. An id can't have a space anyway.

Comment: Identifiers can't have spaces. You need to remove spaces from `ID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change your ids to dont have any spaces (space is an invalid character for IDs) like follows:

```
<div id="Report-One" class="description">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div id="Report-Two" class="description">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

And second (little typo here :)) change:

```
$('description').hide();
```

to:

```
$('.description').hide();
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed the typo. That was spot-on and fixed the whole thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
$('description').hide() // tag selector
```

by

```
$('.description').hide() // class selector
```

Your code as it is, selects elements with tag `description` what is not what you're looking for

**EDIT**

Missed the Id thing (credit to @taxicala). Definitively you need to change your ids.

```
<select id="selReport">
  <option value="ReportOne">Report One</option>
  <option value="ReportTwo">Report Two</option>
  <option value="ReportThree">Report Three</option>
  <option value="ReportFour">Report Four</option>
</select

<div id="ReportOne" class="description">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div id="ReportTwo" class="description">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```